# matlab: optimum amount of points for linear fit

Tags: algorithm, matlab, linear-regression

I want to make a linear fit to few data points, as shown on the image. Since I know the intercept (in this case say 0.05), I want to fit only points which are in the linear region with this particular intercept. In this case it will be lets say points 5:22 (but not 22:30). 
I'm looking for the simple algorithm to determine this optimal amount of points, based on... hmm, that's the question... R^2? Any Ideas how to do it? 
I was thinking about probing R^2 for fits using points 1 to 2:30, 2 to 3:30, and so on, but I don't really know how to enclose it into clear and simple function. For fits with fixed intercept I'm using `polyfit0` (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/272-polyfit0-m) . Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT: 
sample data:

```
intercept = 0.043;
x = 0.01:0.01:0.3;
y = [0.0530642513911393,0.0600786706929529,0.0673485248329648,0.0794662409166333,0.0895915873196170,0.103837395346484,0.107224784565365,0.120300492775786,0.126318699218730,0.141508831492330,0.147135757370947,0.161734674733680,0.170982455701681,0.191799936622712,0.192312642057298,0.204771365716483,0.222689541632988,0.242582251060963,0.252582727297656,0.267390860166283,0.282890010610515,0.292381165948577,0.307990544720676,0.314264952297699,0.332344368808024,0.355781519885611,0.373277721489254,0.387722683944356,0.413648156978284,0.446500064130389;];
```

[image: linear fit]

Comment: Must the points always be contiguous or would an acceptable fit include gaps in the x range? (1:5, 8:23, 25, 30) for example?

Comment: I'd rather keep them contiguous. The 'nonlinearity' for initial points come from localization error and for later points, from typical MSD deviation for the large time. Thus, there is no reason to exclude single points, maybe except some super obvious outsiders (due to i.e. problems with fits for MSD calculation), what usually is not happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is a rather difficult problem to find a *general* solution of.

One approach would be to compute all the slopes/intersects between all consecutive pairs of points, and then do cluster analysis on the intersepts:

```
slopes = diff(y)./diff(x);  
intersepts = y(1:end-1) - slopes.*x(1:end-1);

idx = kmeans(intersepts, 3);

x([idx; 3] == 2)  % the points with the intersepts closest to the linear one.
```

This requires the statistics toolbox (for `kmeans`). This is the best of all methods I tried, although the range of points found this way *might* have a few small holes in it; e.g., when the slopes of two points in the start and end range lie close to the slope of the line, these points will be detected as belonging to the line. This (and other factors) will require a bit more post-processing of the solution found this way.

Another approach (which I failed to construct successfully) is to do a linear fit in a loop, each time increasing the range of points from some point in the middle towards both of the endpoints, and see if the sum of the squared error remains small. This I gave up very quickly, because defining what "small" is is very subjective and must be done in some heuristic way.

I tried a more systematic and robust approach of the above:

```
function test

    %% example data
    slope = 2;
    intercept = 1.5;

    x = linspace(0.1, 5, 100).';

    y         = slope*x + intercept;
    y(1:12)   = log(x(1:12)) + y(12)-log(x(12));
    y(74:100) = y(74:100) + (x(74:100)-x(74)).^8;

    y = y + 0.2*randn(size(y));


    %% simple algorithm

    [X,fn] = fminsearch(@(ii)P(ii, x,y,intercept), [0.5 0.5])

    [~,inds] = P(X, y,x,intercept)

end

function [C, inds] = P(ii, x,y,intercept)
% ii represents fraction of range from center to end,
% So ii lies between 0 and 1. 

    N = numel(x);
    n = round(N/2);  

    ii = round(ii*n);

    inds = min(max(1, n+(-ii(1):ii(2))), N);

    % Solve linear system with fixed intercept
    A = x(inds);
    b = y(inds) - intercept;

    % and return the sum of squared errors, divided by 
    % the number of points included in the set. This 
    % last step is required to prevent fminsearch from
    % reducing the set to 1 point (= minimum possible 
    % squared error). 
    C = sum(((A\b)*A - b).^2)/numel(inds);    

end
```

which only finds a rough approximation to the desired indices (12 and 74 in this example).

When `fminsearch` is run a few dozen times with random starting values (really just `rand(1,2)`), it gets more reliable, but I still wouln't bet my life on it.

If you have the statistics toolbox, use the `kmeans` option.

Comment: sounds very logic, thanks. But in the second step, I can't use (only) 1:m, since most often my optimum range is almost never starting from the 1st point. So, basically, I have to iterate initial point as well, right?

Comment: @Art: Ah, I didn't get that part...then yes, also iterate through the initial points, and then just start in the middle. However, you'll have to take care to require a minimum amount of points for the fit, otherwise, the "best" fit will be between 2 points in the middle :)

Comment: @Art: Oh wait, the intercept is *fixed*?

Comment: yes, the intercept is fixed, and that is the whole idea. So knowing the intercept I want to judge which points are 'the best' (because sometimes there is a second range, also linear, but with totally different intercept, and also slope).

Comment: @Art: OK, see my edit. How often do you have to do this? I mean, do you have to find a few thousand of these ranges, or only a few dozen?

Comment: Both methods are more than enough for me. Thank you Rody for your time and effort spent to solve sometimes very trivial problems of newbies like me, for which programming is a tool to solve other problems. Thanks once again for your help!

Comment: ..and answering your question - fortunately I don't have to do it very often.. its a few times a dataset. Its more like automated fitting suggestion, alternative for call it visual fitting. Thanks!

Comment: @Art: Well, because there are so few datasets to process, and since the automatic methods we've been able to come up with are *somewhat* unreliable, perhaps it's a better idea to bite the bullet and do everything manually. Often, there is just no substitute for a human eye.

Comment: that is why I am saying its more extremely helping fitting suggestion, rather than an absolute value to rely on. I agree that in this case there is no substitute for a human eye.

Comment: ..just a quick note: sometimes I have only one indice on output.. how to avoid it? Its usually happening with messy data...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of data values, I would split the data into a relative small number of overlapping segments, and for each segment calculate the linear fit, or rather the 1-st order coefficient, (remember you know the intercept, which will be same for all segments).

Then, for each coefficient calculate the MSE between this hypothetical line and entire dataset, choosing the coefficient which yields the smallest MSE.